# How to specify the location of an image in css in python flask

Tags: css, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to make a website in flask and I want to put an image on the website it works using the img tag but I cannot resize or do anything to it. I want to use it as a background and want it to be responsive but I can't, the css files can't find the specified image.
[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYdhG.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Сheck your Flask application initialization. You need to specify static path something like this `app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/')`

Comment: I've tried this, and it's not working as a matter of fact I've found that most of the static folder is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have the below project directory for the `static` folder:

`static/
  └── css/
       └──style.css
  └── img/
       └──image.png`

In the `CSS` file you would have to give the relative path. Also, if you are using the above directory structure you can use the below `CSS` commands in `CSS` file:

```
background: url(../img/image.png)no-repeat 0px 0px;
background-size: cover;
```

This will import the image from `static/img/` and then you can all the CSS tag to make it responsive.

Comment: It is not working and in fact, I've found this new error.127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2020 13:28:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2020 13:28:25] "GET /js/scripts HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2020 13:28:25] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2020 13:28:25] "GET /js/scripts HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: Oh, thanks after restarting VS code the new 404 errors went, but the image is still not appearing on the website. Stil back to square one

Comment: static/
  └── css/
       └──style.css
  └── img/
       └──image.png                                                                                                                                  Also I'm a beginner so I don't know, what is this view file.                                                  Are you talking about the template?

Comment: Specify the static directory path like `app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')`. If required you can upload the project structure screenshot so that it is easy for me to solve your problem. Also, I believe you have added the above code in `style.css` file and using that `class` in `div` tag in HTML.

Comment: [Flask project Structure](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/layout/) you can go through this once if you need more clarifications in the directory structure in Flask.